# Combine two rows in select query having same id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT 
`sys_forms`.`FormID`,
`sys_forms`.`FormName`,
`sys_forms`.`FormCIPath`,
`sys_forms_in_groups`.`IsMenuLink`,
`sys_forms_in_groups`.`GroupID`

FROM (`sys_forms`) INNER JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` 
ON `sys_forms_in_groups`.`FormID` = `sys_forms`.`FormID` WHERE `GroupID` = 1
UNION
SELECT 
`sys_forms`.`FormID`,
`sys_forms`.`FormName`,
`sys_forms`.`FormCIPath`,
`sys_forms_in_groups`.`IsMenuLink`,
`sys_forms_in_groups`.`GroupID`

FROM (`sys_forms`) INNER JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` 
ON `sys_forms_in_groups`.`FormID` = `sys_forms`.`FormID` WHERE `GroupID` = 2
```

it is returning me this below data.

[image]

As you can see, there are two identical `FormID`.

What i want that if the id's are same then rows should be merged but `GroupID` is different for both identical FormID's.

So i want them to join in CSV format so that the result would be

```
FormID FormName        -  -   GroupID
-------------------------------------------------
48     FormsIn Groups  -  -    1,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specified result can be returned with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT f.FormID
     , f.FormName
     , f.FormCIPath
     , MAX(g.IsMenuLink) AS IsMenuLink
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.GroupID ORDER BY g.GroupID) AS GroupIDs
  FROM `sys_forms` f 
  JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` g
    ON g.FormID = f.FormID
   AND g.GroupID IN (1,2)
 GROUP BY f.formID
```

The `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate will combine multiple values into a comma separated list. (A different delimiter can be specified, the default is a comma.)

We use the `MAX` aggregate around the `IsMenuLink` column so we get a non-NULL value in place of NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Your first query can just be written as:

```
SELECT sf.`FormID`, sf.`FormName`, sf.`FormCIPath`, sfig.`IsMenuLink`, sfig.`GroupID`
FROM `sys_forms` sf INNER JOIN
     `sys_forms_in_groups` sfig
     ON sfig.`FormID` = sf.`FormID`
WHERE `GroupID` IN (1, 2);
```

Note the use of table aliases and the single `where` clause with `in`.

To get what you want, use `group by` and include only the columns you want:

```
SELECT sf.`FormID`, sf.`FormName`, 
       group_concat(sfig.`GroupID`) as groupids
FROM `sys_forms` sf INNER JOIN
     `sys_forms_in_groups` sfig
     ON sfig.`FormID` = sf.`FormID`
WHERE `GroupID` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY sf.`FormID`, sf.`FormName`, sf.`FormCIPath`, sfig.`IsMenuLink`;
```